# WCF Message Security continues to work with certificate removed

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, encryption, certificate

I'm developing a product that consists of a WCF service and several WCF clients deployed to different locations. In order to secure the service, I configured WCF to use Message Security via certificates.

In detail, these are my service configuration files:
[Web.config](http://pastebin.com/QVAjaCEM), [App.config](http://pastebin.com/dJ3RaQPQ)

This is working fine as far as I can tell, even when the certificate is stored on a SmartCard (WCF even pops up a dialog asking me to enter the SmartCard's PIN in order to unlock the certificate).

But removing the SmartCard after the initial security negotiation took place does not have any effect on the connection - I can still invoke methods on the web service.

What's happening?

- Does WCF message security work similar to HTTPS, where a symmetric key is established during the initial security negotiation and after that, the certificate is no longer needed?
- Or could it be that I have set up the service to only use the certificate to authenticate the client, but messages aren't encrypted at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your security configuration uses security context (default for WsHttpBinding). Security context (implementation of WS-SecureConversation) indeed works similarly to HTTPS. It uses certificate only to initial authentication and generation of security token which is used to secure following communication from the same service proxy instance. The context is established be service proxy instance and it also establish WCF session which is subject of timeout.

Comment: Sounds logical, though I have one observation to add: if I use a certificate with a password-protected private key, the client *still* authenticates -  without asking me for the key (and I didn't save it on the certificate store). I wonder how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
  </security>
```

Try setting the **establishSecurityContext** to false.